# Racket has a little cinconsistence

Tags: racket

I have a question about racket, this is the problem:

build a function that is able to build figures in Canvas on drRacket, this hasto receive a list of structures called figures with the next  items:

a)Type: Can be "Square", "Circle" or Line

b) Color: It can be "Red", "Yellow", "Green" or "Blue".

c) Size: In the case of the square is the Side, in the circle is the Radio and in the case of the line the
next point (For example, a point with a coordinate of 0,0 if it is assigned size 50, the next
point will be 50,50).

d) Center of the figure: It is a posn structure (available in Dr Racket), keep in mind that the center
of the square is the position.

The size of the canvas is 400 by 400, so keep in mind the figures can not get out

so, I tried this:

```
( define-struct figura (tipo color tamaño centro)) 

(define figuras
 (cons(make−figura "Cuadrado" "Azul" 50 (make−posn 50 50))
 (cons(make−figura "Cuadrado" "Rojo" 100 (make−posn 100 150))
 (cons(make−figura "Circulo" "Verde" 50 (make−posn 200 50))`enter code here`
 (cons(make−figura "Circulo" "Amarillo" 100 (make−posn 300 300)))empty))))
```

and it says this line:     (cons(make−figura "Cuadrado" "Rojo" 100 (make−posn 100 150))
 has the next problem:
make−figura: this function is not defined

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code and got the same error message. When I first pasted your code in, however, I hit this function in Racket's source code:

```
(normalize-string-info "The string you pasted contains ligatures or other non-normalized characters. Normalize them?")
```

I'm not a Racket expert but I guessed that was the issue so I typed out your code snippet myself and it ran fine.

```
(define-struct figura (tipo color tamano centro))

(define figuras
  (cons (make-figura "Cuadardo" "Azul" 50 (make-posn 50 50))
    (cons (make-figura "Cuadardo" "Rojo" 100 (make-posn 100 150))
      (cons (make-figura "Circulo" "Verde" 50 (make-posn 200 50))
        (cons (make-figura "Circulo" "Amarillo" 100 (make-posn 300 300))
          '())))))
```

Comment: Yes, the “−” character (U+2212 MINUS SIGN) is not the same as the “-” character (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS)! The former is the character in the OP’s code, but the latter is the usual ASCII character used by Racket.

Comment: That's the more detailed answer I couldn't provide! Thanks